# Swift location manager

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, location, cllocationmanager

I have problem with location in Swift.

On simulator works fine but on device not working

I use simulator iPhone 6 iOS 8.3 and device iPhone 6 iOS 8.3

my code:

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate,
CLLocationManagerDelegate {

  var window: UIWindow?
  var locationManager: CLLocationManager! = nil
  var isExecutingInBackground = false

  func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!,
    didUpdateToLocation newLocation: CLLocation!,
    fromLocation oldLocation: CLLocation!){
      if isExecutingInBackground{
        println(newLocation);
        locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
      } else {
        /* We are in the foreground. Do any processing that you wish */
      }
  }

 func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool
 {
    locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    return true
  }



  func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {
    isExecutingInBackground = true
    var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(30, target: self, selector: Selector("update"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)


    /* Reduce the accuracy to ease the strain on
    iOS while we are in the background */
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters
  }

    func update() {
        println("test");
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }

  func applicationWillEnterForeground(application: UIApplication) {
    isExecutingInBackground = false

    /* Now that our app is in the foreground again, let's increase the location
    detection accuracy */
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
  }
}
```

I want get location every 30 seconds

so why not working on device?

Comment: You shouldn't call startUpdatingLocation until you have confirmed that you have location permission. Also `didUpdateToLocation` is deprecated. Finally, is location services enabled on your device?  The NSTimer won't execute when you are in the background, but it doesn't do anything anyway

Comment: yes, location services enabled
 When i click menu button i get location but after 30 seconds i can't get location

Comment: You won't necessarily get location updates every 30 seconds. You get location updates when your location changes more than the reporting threshold. Are you moving your device?

Comment: yes, if i move stil not working...

Comment: I made a simple example that works for me, from a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35973586/3410437

Answer (score 5):

Bottom line, for background updates, you either use the "significant-change" service or you have to request background location services (which Apple limits to apps that have compelling need for location updates, i.e. for actual navigation apps).

See [Tracking the User’s Location](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW25) section in the *App Programming Guide for iOS:*

> #### Tracking the User’s Location
>
> There are several ways to track the user’s location in the background, most of which do not actually require your app to run continuously in the background:
>
> - The significant-change location service (Recommended)
> - Foreground-only location services
> - Background location services
>
> The significant-change location service is highly recommended for apps that do not need high-precision location data. With this service, location updates are generated only when the user’s location changes significantly; thus, it is ideal for social apps or apps that provide the user with noncritical, location-relevant information. If the app is suspended when an update occurs, the system wakes it up in the background to handle the update. If the app starts this service and is then terminated, the system relaunches the app automatically when a new location becomes available. This service is available in iOS 4 and later, and it is available only on devices that contain a cellular radio.
>
> The foreground-only and background location services both use the standard location Core Location service to retrieve location data. The only difference is that the foreground-only location services stop delivering updates if the app is ever suspended, which is likely to happen if the app does not support other background services or tasks. Foreground-only location services are intended for apps that only need location data while they are in the foreground.
>
> You enable location support from the Background modes section of the Capabilities tab in your Xcode project. (You can also enable this support by including the `UIBackgroundModes` key with the location value in your app’s `Info.plist` file.) Enabling this mode does not prevent the system from suspending the app, but it does tell the system that it should wake up the app whenever there is new location data to deliver. Thus, this key effectively lets the app run in the background to process location updates whenever they occur.
>
> > Important: You are encouraged to use the standard services sparingly or use the significant location change service instead. Location services require the active use of an iOS device’s onboard radio hardware. Running this hardware continuously can consume a significant amount of power. If your app does not need to provide precise and continuous location information to the user, it is best to minimize the use of location services.
>
> For information about how to use each of the different location services in your app, see Location and Maps Programming Guide.