# Swift 2 – Can't get user location with CLLocationManager

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, xcode7, cllocationmanager

**Here is my VC code:**

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!
    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        mapView.showsUserLocation = true
    }

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        mapView.showsUserLocation = (status == .AuthorizedAlways)
    }

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        let locValue:CLLocationCoordinate2D = manager.location!.coordinate
        print("locations = \(locValue.latitude) \(locValue.longitude)")
    }
}
```

I have also added `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` in my plist file. And I have the `CoreLocation` and `MapKit` frameworks, any idea why this is not working?  It doesn't show the user location on the map nor does it print out the user's coordinates.  Haven't found anything online on on stack overflow.

Comment: Run the Settings app. Go to the bottom where the apps are listed. Select your app's settings. Is location disabled?

Comment: No, location is enabled

Comment: Just noticed, where do you call `startUpdatingLocation` on `locationManager`?

Comment: in `func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus)` check if status is `AuthorizedWhenInUse` and then start updating locations :)

Comment: Ah that was my problem! I forgot to call `startUpdatingLocation`, but it still is not showing the user location on the map. Thanks @rmaddy

Answer (score 5):

This works for me

Swift 2 - (Xcode 7.2.1)

**ViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    var locationManager: CLLocationManager = CLLocationManager()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

        self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()

        let latestLocation = locations.last

        let latitude = String(format: "%.4f", latestLocation!.coordinate.latitude)
        let longitude = String(format: "%.4f", latestLocation!.coordinate.longitude)

        print("Latitude: \(latitude)")
        print("Longitude: \(longitude)")
    }
}
```

**info.plist**

Add a new line

*Information Property List:* NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription

*Type:* String

*Value:* The application uses this information to show you your location

Answer (score 0):

Try getting the location by getting the last object for the array `locations` in the method `locationManager(_:,didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocations])` .

Something like this:

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        let locValue:CLLocationCoordinate2D = locations.last!
        print("locations = \(locValue.latitude) \(locValue.longitude)")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to use these location access permission in your plist.

1. **NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription**
2. NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription

you are not using always and in InUse permiossion

Note by Apple:

This app has attempted to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage description. The app's **Info.plist must contain both NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription and NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription** keys with string values explaining to the user how the app uses this data